# how to decompose an image into magnitude and phase and reconstruct it again using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, fft, phase, magnitude

How can I decompose an image (e.g. Lena) into magnitude image and phase image and reconstruct it again from those two images using Matlab?

Here is the code I have written in Matlab but I dont know why the reconstructed image is too dark or too bright!

```matlab
I = imread('lena.png');
I_fft = fft2(I);
I_amp = abs(I_fft);
I_phase = angle(I_fft);

I_fft_recon = I_amp .* exp(I_phase);
I_recon = ifft2(I_fft_recon);
imshow(I_recon)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to multiply the phase by the complex unit [`j`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14790740/1714410):

```
I_fft_recon = I_amp .* exp(j * I_phase);
```

Everything else should be just fine.

BTW, you might want to convert the image to `double` before processing

```
I = im2double(I);
```

Comment: if I calculate reconstruction error, `I_error = I - I_recon;` there are values in the image. what are they?

Comment: @MJay verify that these values are very small. They are probably due to numerical issues. See e.g., [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/686439/1714410).